# HTTP Header not set using Curl in C++

Tags: c++, http, curl, header, thrift

I'm very new to HTTP commands and the libcurl library, so there is a good chance that I'm not understanding something fundamental. That said, I am trying to set headers using curl in C++ but when I try to get the Content-Type, a null value is returned. I am not able to figure out why this is happening. Here is the piece of code:

```
// HTTP headers to send with request
   struct curl_slist* headers = nullptr;

// Set Content-Type to application/x-hybrid-thrift-binary
   headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/x-hybrid-thrift-binary");

   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
   CURLcode ret = curl_easy_perform(curl);

// Extract the content-type
   char *ct = nullptr;
   ret = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE, &ct);
   if(!ret) {
     printf("Content-Type: %s\n", ct);
   }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!!!

Comment: Just an especulation, but you are appending to `headers`, which has not been assigned any memory address to it. Maybe `... headers = new curl_list();` As said, it is an especulation, I don't know anything about curl.

Comment: I am printing the size of the headers using `ret = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE, &size);` and it returns a non-zero value which I guess means that it is appending to the headers.

Comment: You are right. I was wrong. Based on [this](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_slist_append.html)

Comment: Another wild guess: Are you sure the header is returned at all? [Seems not mandatory](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html#BodyType) so maybe it is just missing? The [lidcurl docs say the same](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE.html)

Answer (score 2):

From the [libcurl docs](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE.html):

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> #include <curl/curl.h> 
>
>  CURLcode curl_easy_getinfo(CURL *handle, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE, char **ct);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> Pass a pointer to a char pointer to receive the content-type of the downloaded object. This is the value read from the Content-Type: field. **If you get NULL, it means that the server didn't send a valid Content-Type header or that the protocol used doesn't support this.**
>
> RETURN VALUE
>
> Returns `CURLE_OK` if the option is supported, and `CURLE_UNKNOWN_OPTION` if not.

Comment: What does the line **the protocol used doesn't support this.** mean? Specifically, what does **this** stand for? Does it mean that the protocol I am using does not support curl?

Comment: [A lot of protocols are supported](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html). This particular header is very likely not supported by all of them. This part is probably not really relevant in your specific case.